# Error function not invoked in AJAX using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
 $("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "session.php",
       data: "name=John123&location=Boston",
       success: function(a, msg2){
          $('#feedback').removeClass().addClass('success').text(a +' '+msg2).fadeIn('slow');

       },

         error: function(a, b, c){
              $('#feedback').removeClass().addClass('error').text('This is' +b).fadeIn('slow');
           },
```

I'm trying to invoke error function using the following code in PHP:

```
if ($_POST['name'] != "John") {
        $message['error'] = true;
        $message['message'] = "Hmm, please enter a subject in the subject field.";

        echo json_encode($message);
}
else
{
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
```

But I'm always getting success function invoked. Is there any way i can get error function invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why won't you do something like this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "session.php",
        data: "name=John&location=Boston",
        success: function(a, msg2){
            if(a.error) {
                $('#feedback').removeClass().addClass('error').text('This is' +a.message).fadeIn('slow');
            }
            else {
                $('#feedback').removeClass().addClass('success').text(a.name +' '+msg2).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And:

```
if ($_POST['name'] != "John") {
    $message['error'] = true;
    $message['message'] = "Hmm, please enter a subject in the subject field.";
}
else
{
    $message['error'] = false;
    $message['name'] = $_POST['name'];
}
echo json_encode($message);
```

The error function is invoked only when the ajax fails, so instead you can check if the ajax returned that the error exists or not.

Comment: Yes i can do that and it is just the alternative way. But you know what if i get any error while validating the data the error message will be parsed through "success" function, which I feel is not a good programming practice.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the HTTP status code to `500` (or anything else `>= 400`) to indicate that there was an error.

Comment: Thanks. But tell me how should i set this code in PHP so that it returns error and invoke the error function.